# plyr along two dimensions (ddply)

Tags: list, r, dataframe, plyr

I have a data frame that looks like this (simplified for exposition):

```
date id value
d1 id1 v1
d2 id1 v2
d1 id2 v3
d2 id2 v4
```

I would like to break this apart by id, run a rolling regression on each id (so for each id there will be N regressions), pick out the rsquared and assemble this back to a dataframe.  My method for doing this was:

```
roll_reg <- function(df) {
    T <- with(df, min(nlen(xs_ret), nlen(xs_mkt), nlen(smb), nlen(hml), nlen(umd)))
    OFFSET <- 3

    themodels <- as.list(rep(NA, OFFSET))
    #120 days rolling period
    if (T>OFFSET) {
        #the first OFFSET models are na

        for (i in seq(OFFSET+1, T)) {
            idx <- seq(i-OFFSET-1,i)
            themodels[i] <- list(with(df, 
                      lm(xs_ret[idx]~xs_mkt[idx]+smb[idx]+hml[idx]+umd[idx])))

        }

        return(themodels)
    }
    else { return(NA) }
}

models <- dlply(dt_df, "id", roll_reg)
```

Then I was going to reassemble everything using

```
ldply(models, function(x) {summary(x)$r.squared})
```

This does not work since models is a list of lists, and x is a list of models.  However, if my `function(x)` returns a list by `cat`-ing all the rsquared into a list I get an error because `ldply` expects `function(x)` to return an atomic result.  Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This R code reproduces the problem:

```
library(plyr)

dat = data.frame(date = rep(paste("d", 1:100, sep = ""), length = 100),
             id = rep(paste("id", 1:10, sep = ""), each = 100),
             value = runif(100))

make.lm = function(input) {
  lm1 = lm(value~date, input[1:50,])
  lm2 = lm(value~date, input[1:50,])
  return(list(lm1, lm2))
}

models = dlply(dat, c("id"), make.lm)
coefs = ldply(models, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)
# Error in summary(x)$r.squared : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

This works:

```
models = dlply(dat, c("id"), make.lm)
coefs = ldply(models, function(x) 
             ldply(x, function(y) 
              return(data.frame(rsq = summary(y)$r.squared))))
coefs$id2 = rep(1:2, each = 2)

> head(coefs)
    id rsq id2
1  id1   1   1
2  id1   1   1
3 id10   1   2
4 id10   1   2
5  id2   1   1
6  id2   1   1
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: also, is there a way that i could preserve the dates as well so that they are output with the coefs here?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do

```
ldply(models, laply, function(x) {summary(x)$r.squared})
```

Basically, since your `x` is a list of models, do another l*ply over that.  I'm not sure the return value is right because it is not reproducible.

Comment: that's actually one of the things i tried to do, but it looks as if ldply expects the output of your function to be atomic and not a list... this seems strange to me but could make sense since it's trying to convert each entry to a row in a dataframe..?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `rapply` which is a recursive version of `lapply`. You could try something like this

```
rapply(models, function(model) summary(model)$r.squared)
```

This will only return a vector of r.squared, and you will have to recreate your data frame.

Comment: It seems that raply is not the recursive version of lapply, but rather it runs replicates of the expression you pass to it.